# Jquery Portfolio Wordpress tags by category

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm making a filterable portfolio using jquery. I have different categories and I'm getting all the posts within one category and then sorting them by their tags. This works fine with one word tags, but it does not work when the tag is more than one word. How can it work with more than one word tag?

My code:

```
    <div class="tagwrapper">
    <div class="posttags">
        <?php
        query_posts('category_name=Sport');
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $posttags = get_the_tags();

            // print_r($posttags);
            // echo gettype($posttags);
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    //                echo gettype($tag);
                    //echo $tag->name;
                    $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> name; //USING JUST $tag MAKING $all_tags_arr A MULTI-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY, WHICH DOES WORK WITH array_unique
                }                    
            }

        endwhile; endif; 
            $unique_tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags_arr); //REMOVES DUPLICATES

        if ($unique_tags_arr) {
            echo '<ul class="jquery">';
            echo '<li data-filter=".filterable">';
            echo "Alle";
            echo '</li>';
            foreach ($unique_tags_arr as &$value) {
                echo '<li data-filter=".'.$value .'"> '.$value.'</li>'; 

            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="news">
        <?php          

         while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    //generate the article list for all articles within the sports category
                    //the $tags_class variable is a whitespace delimited string of tags for this post

                    //print_r($value);
                    $posttags = get_the_tags();

                    echo '<article class="filterable ';
                    if ($posttags) {
                      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                        echo $tag->name . ' '; 
                      }                   
                    } 
                    echo '">';
                    ?>


                    <h3> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>

                    <?php echo '</article>'; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `$value` can be a string with whitespace such as `my cool category`. And the filterable ruleset isn't built to handle whitespace as 1 value. What you actually want is to check for whitespace in the string and then replace it with `-`.

```
if(preg_match('/\s/', $value) $value = str_replace(" ", "-", $value);
```

Then you will get:

```
my-cool-category
```

You will also need to make this modification in the following code:

```
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    if(preg_match('/\s/', $tag) $tag = str_replace(" ", "-", $tag);
}
```

Comment: Well, it is better to use the native `sanitize_title()` function in order to transform category name. I.e. `$value = sanitize title($value)`. Don't get a wrong impression by the function name, it is not meant to sanitize a title for further usage as a page/post title. It takes a title string and returns it to be used in a URL.

Comment: @bodi0 Most certainly it is a function that can be used as a substitution but by no means are wrappers better than native php functions.

Comment: The usage of regex engine here is more expensive that native WP function from performance perspective.

Comment: @bodi0 please provide proof of this statement.

Comment: Well, take a look at the source of the aforementioned function, I do not want to explain/spam with unnecessary code.

Comment: @bodi0 So what you're saying is that you can't be bothered to find any reputable source backing your claims, yet you wish to make blanket statements about performance gains?

Comment: Is this question or accusation? Or you are the one, who do not want to bother looking at the source code of the proven and useful function?

Comment: @bodi0 You've got to be kidding me here. I ask your for proof and you tell me to go find it myself? Pretty sure that's not how this works. Anyway, `sanitize_title()` calls `apply_filters` which is slower than simply using a regexp match in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" and I'm not experienced enough in PHP to find the error. I did get it working by using "$tag = str_replace(' ', '-', $tag);" but I then it also displays the - frontend and that does not look good.